# React Router giving error cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am testing out React-Router and currently all of my code is in index.html file. When I run the app I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined
at Object.createTransitionManager (ReactRouter.min.js:1)
at Object.componentWillMount (ReactRouter.min.js:1)
at react-dom.js:4802
at measureLifeCyclePerf (react-dom.js:4529)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4801)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4712)
at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4825)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4712)
at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11542)
```

Here is my code. Please note this code is inside index.html file.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
      return (
          <div>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>Stuff</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
          content
          </div>
          </div>
      );
    }

  });

  ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRouter.Router>
      <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
      </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>,
    container
    );

  </script>
```

Comment: Try removing `history={hashHistory}`

Comment: @Kenan Thanks see the updated post with the updated error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `history` prop in your `Router` definition. Add that and I think the error should go away

```
var browserHistory=ReactRouter.browserHistory;
ReactDOM.render(
    <ReactRouter.Router history={browserHistory}>
      <ReactRouter.Route path="/" component={App}>
      </ReactRouter.Route>
    </ReactRouter.Router>,
    container
    );
```